# Adding groups to ListView depending on the data in a list

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have written simple code which loops through a list object and create groups in `ListView` depending on the data in the list. I have a list object of type `List<Assignment>` where `Assignment` is a class as follows.

```
public class Assignment
{
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int ImageIndex { get; set; }
}
```

Now, the list object have several assignments with different `TimeSpan`. My job is to group together all the `Assignment`s with similar `TimeSpan` into one group and add this group to the `ListView`. The following code works perfectly fine for me. Still, I would love to know if there is better way of doing this.

The list passed into the function is sorted by `TimeSpan`.

```
private void FeedDataToPane(List<Assignment> assignmentList)
{
    ListViewGroup _listViewGrp;
    ListViewItem _listViewItem;

    MonitorPane.BeginUpdate();
    MonitorPane.Groups.Clear();
    MonitorPane.SmallImageList = imageList;

    for (int i = 0; i < assignmentList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            _listViewGrp = new ListViewGroup(assignmentList[i].Time.ToString());
            MonitorPane.Groups.Add(_listViewGrp);

            _listViewItem = new ListViewItem(assignmentList[i].Type, assignmentList[i].ImageIndex, _listViewGrp);
            _listViewItem.SubItems.Add(assignmentList[i].Description);
            MonitorPane.Items.Add(_listViewItem);
        }
        else
        {
            if (assignmentList[i].Time.Equals(assignmentList[i - 1].Time))
            {
                _listViewItem = new ListViewItem(assignmentList[i].Type, assignmentList[i].ImageIndex, _listViewGrp);
                _listViewItem.SubItems.Add(assignmentList[i].Description);
                MonitorPane.Items.Add(_listViewItem);
            }
            else
            {
                _listViewGrp = new ListViewGroup(assignmentList[i].Time.ToString());
                MonitorPane.Groups.Add(_listViewGrp);

                _listViewItem = new ListViewItem(assignmentList[i].Type, assignmentList[i].ImageIndex, _listViewGrp);
                _listViewItem.SubItems.Add(assignmentList[i].Description);
                MonitorPane.Items.Add(_listViewItem);
            }
        }
    }

    MonitorPane.EndUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible with the help of LINQ to reduce your code to this (assuming, of course, the version of .NET you're using will allow it):

```
private void FeedDataToPane(IEnumerable<Assignment> assignmentList)
{
    MonitorPane.BeginUpdate();
    MonitorPane.Groups.Clear();
    MonitorPane.SmallImageList = imageList;

    assignmentList
        .GroupBy(assignment => assignment.Time, CreateListViewGroup)
        .ToList();

    MonitorPane.EndUpdate();
}

private static ListViewGroup CreateListViewGroup(TimeSpan time, IEnumerable<Assignment> assignments)
{
    var group = new ListViewGroup(time.ToString());
    MonitorPane.Groups.Add(group);

    foreach (var assignment in assignments)
    {
        var item = new ListViewItem(assignment.Type, assignment.ImageIndex, group);
        item.SubItems.Add(assignment.Description);
        MonitorPane.Items.Add(item);
    }

    return group;
}
```

Comment: Hi George, When I add this code of yours, the CreateListViewGroup is not getting called.

Comment: @Govs Forgot that `GroupBy` is deferred. Fixed.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain what is horrendously wrong with the answer?

Comment: Cool, That works like a charm. Clean. I am going to accept this as answer. Who ever down voted please care to explain if you have a better answer.

Comment: Hi George, I searched online and read through some posts and blogs about GroupBy method. But I still don't fully understand how it works. I understand that it groups by time and then pass each group to the CreateListViewGroup method. But the method returns group back. How and where does this returned group gets handled? Do you have any link which can explain this?

Comment: @Govs The specific overload of `GroupBy` used in this example can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549393(v=vs.100).aspx). There's two things to note here. The first being that `GroupBy` uses deferred execution (which you can read more about [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx)), hence the need for `ToList`.

Comment: @Govs The second thing being that `CreateListViewGroup` is called for each group that is created by the `GroupBy` method. I chose to do it this way for readability because you're doing some additional logic as you're grouping. Alternatively, if you have an `AddRange` method on `MonitorPane.Groups`, what you could do is use the return value of `ToList` and pass in the groups as a whole.

Comment: @Govs I understand your confusion with the method returning a `ListViewGroup` as it isn't actually used. Basically, as I said before, it's done in this way because you're executing additional logic as you're grouping, and I need to return a `ListViewGroup` to satisfy the contract of the `GroupBy` method (i.e. I can't return `void`). If you look at the code example on the `GroupBy` method on MSDN I gave you, you'll see that it's simply returning an anonymous object and not doing additional stuff like you're doing here.